# How to fix the current inequation solver and is there a better approach/library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, sympy

I'm trying to write a Python script that solves the given system of four inequalities with three variables:

```
х * 31  +  y * 2.9   +  z * 25  <= 160
x * 0   +  y * 23    +  z * 1.3 <= 160
x * 3.6 +  y * 0.9   +  z * 33  <= 50
x * 165 +  y * 110.9 +  z * 402 <= 1730
```

So far I've come up with the following code:

```py
from sympy.abc import x, y, z
from sympy import solve_rational_inequalities, Poly
    
a = solve_rational_inequalities([
  ((Poly(31*x + 2.9*y + 25*z), Poly(1)), '<=', Poly(160)),
  ((Poly(x), Poly(23*y), Poly(1.3*z), Poly(0)), '<=', Poly(160)),
  ((Poly(3.6*x), Poly(0.9*y), Poly(33*z), Poly(0)), '<=', Poly(50)),
  ((Poly(165*x), Poly(110.9*y), Poly(402*z), Poly(0)), '<=', Poly(1730))
])
    
print(a)
```

Upon executing, it I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/main.py", line 5, in <module>
  ((Poly(31*x + 2.9*y + 25*z), Poly(1)), '<=', Poly(160)),
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 164, in __new__
  return cls._from_expr(rep, opt)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 294, in _from_expr
  return cls._from_dict(rep, opt)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/polys/polytools.py", line 231, in _from_dict
  raise GeneratorsNeeded(sympy.polys.polyerrors.GeneratorsNeeded: 
  can't initialize from 'dict' without generators
```

What might be the problem, and how can it be fixed?
Also, is there a better library for solving such problems?

Comment: The error is generated by `((Poly(31*x + 2.9*y + 25*z), Poly(1)), '<=', Poly(160))`.  It hasn't even gotten to calling the solve.  I haven't worked with this solver, but your expressions don't look like its documented example(s).

Comment: On the face of it, there might not be a unique solution to a system of inequalities, so maybe you want a characterization of the convex hull of the points satisfying the inequalities? or there is an objective function in the picture which you want to minimize or maximize? Looks like an interesting problem, but maybe you can say more about what you mean by "solve" in this context.

Comment: @RobertDodier The context is that I want to find all whole number combinations of X, Y, Z which satisfy the inequalities. Additionally, the coefficients like 31, 2.9, 25 and so on will be different numbers each time coming as parameters a, b and c. In the example given even X = Y = Z (> 0 and <= 1) satisfy the conditions.

Comment: See work at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/22389

Comment: @DeyvidDimitrov Okay, terrific. Maybe it would help if you edit your question to mention that. If I'm not mistaken, it appears that this problem falls under the heading of "Diophantine inequalities"; a web search finds some resources, e.g.: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69966/algorithm-for-solving-systems-of-linear-diophantine-inequalities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the best way to solve this, but using code that is already available [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/22389#issuecomment-1211097848) you can do the following:

```py
>>> from symyp import *
>>> from sympy.abc import x,y,z
>>> eqs = [31*x + 2.9*y + 25*z <= 160, 23*y + 1.3*z <= 160, 3.6*x + 0.9*y + 33*z <= 50, 165*x + 110.9*y + 402*z <= 1730]
>>> eqs = [nsimplify(i, rational=True) for i in eqs]
>>> sol = solve_linear_inequalities(eqs,(x,y,z))
```

You will obtain a solution for y indicating it is in `Interval(-oo, min(...functions of x and z...))`. Doing the same for functions of x and z in the `min` gives a solution for z like `Interval(-oo, min(...const or functions of x...))`. Finally, doing the same for functions of x in the min indicates that x is in Interval(-oo, 5.16). So for x in range(1,6) you can calculate the corresponding ranges for z and then y. Here is just a brute force loop:

```py
>>> yy = sol[y]
for xx in range(6):
    for zz in range(6):
        yi = yy.subs(x,xx).subs(z,zz).intersection(Range(1,oo))
        if not yi:continue
        print(xx,yi,zz)
```

which gives

```
0 Range(1, 7, 1) 0
0 Range(1, 7, 1) 1
1 Range(1, 7, 1) 0
1 Range(1, 7, 1) 1
2 Range(1, 7, 1) 0
2 Range(1, 7, 1) 1
3 Range(1, 7, 1) 0
3 Range(1, 7, 1) 1
4 Range(1, 7, 1) 0
4 Range(1, 3, 1) 1
5 Range(1, 2, 1) 0
```

Without a objective function to maximize, it looks like there are a finite number of whole number solutions for your equations. Perhaps this is encouragement enough to get you moving towards a more general solution for your problem? Also, if you give a range of interest for x, y, and z, that will help, e.g. if they are all positive then a solution for each variable is given

```py
>>> sol = solve_linear_inequalities(eqs + [x>0,y>0,z>0], (x, y, z))
>>> for i in sol:
...     print(i, sol[i])
z Interval(0, 50/33)
x Interval(0, Min(160/31 - 25*z/31, 346/33 - 134*z/55, 125/9 - 55*z/6))
y Interval(0, Min(160/23 - 13*z/230, -310*x/29 - 250*z/29 + 1600/29, -4*x - 110*z/3 + 500/9, -1650*x/1109 - 4020*z/1109 + 17300/1109))
```

So pick a value from the range for z, calculate the valid ranges for x and select an x value, and finally compute the valid range for y.